# Custom inspectors cropped since 2019.1

Tags: unity

Since updating to 2019.1, I have noticed that my custom editors are not drawing properly. It is kinda like they were being cropped, for some reason.

Here is an example:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    serializedObject.Update();

    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(scale);
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(threshold);
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(index);
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(seed);


    Rect r = new Rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(r, Color.red);
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

As you can see, the objects rendered with EditorGUILayout seem to be rendering fine, but when I draw the Rect with `EditorGUI`, the inspector crops part of the Rect.

What is going on??

[image]

Comment: Have your tried reserving the height you want in the layout pass using eg. [GetControlRect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect.html)?

Comment: Im not sure how that would work. Could you show me a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `EditorGUILayout` methods, Unity keeps track of how much space each control uses, so it can arrange the following ones to avoid overlap.

But non-Layout methods like `EditorGUI.DrawRect`, it doesn't use this layout system or track the space you're using.

It looks like older versions of Unity would let drawing overflow past the layout-reserved space, while the version you're using limits the drawing area to what you've reserved. (Or clears unclaimed area below where it thinks the bottom of the control sits)

We can fix this by reserving some extra space with:

```
float extraHeight = 100f;
var space = EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect(false, extraHeight);
```

This doesn't draw a control on its own, just holds space for whatever you want to draw there.

Comment: Kinda of a hack, because I have to "guess" the height Im gonna use. But it works at least. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a situation where you don't know the height of the items you're drawing?

Comment: Well, if I have something like an array, where the control increases it size, depending on the amount of elements, it might get complex. Specially if we are talking about complex elements, that take more than a line, like for instance a reorderable list.

I mean, I could always calculate it, but its kinda of a pain

Comment: The list or array would be drawn with Layout methods that already account for their height, would they not? If you're rolling your own, you can attack this in pieces, and make each individual control responsible for computing its needed space, so your wrapping code doesn't need to know all those details or make adjustments every time you change a control.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there are ways to do this. It is just a pain :(